# Laravel Collective onclick in SELECT

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to add laravel collective onclick in "select"? My below code does not work:

```
{{Form::select('material_selector', [
        '10' => 'Cotton', 
        '20' => 'Wet Look',
        '30' => 'Crocodile',
    ], null, ['placeholder' => 'Select Material'],['class'=>'form-control','onclick'=> 'showSelectedValue()' ])
}}
```

Comment: Use event handlers using e.g. [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). `onclick` handlers are bad practice

Comment: @harinsamaranayake Please mark the answer if you found it

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use jQuery. Then you can address your select element as follows

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form-control[name="material_selector"]').on('change', showSelectedValue);
  
  function showSelectedValue(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    console.log(target.val() + " = " + target.find('option:selected').text());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="material_selector" class="form-control">
  <option value="10">Cotton</option>
  <option value="20">Wet Look</option>
  <option value="30">Crocodile</option>
</select>
```

If you are really need to use the `onClick` attribute you can try this

```php
{{Form::select(
    'material_selector', // name attribute of the select
    ['10' => 'Cotton', '20' => 'Wet Look', '30' => 'Crocodile'], // option values
    null, // selected value, for example '20'
    ['placeholder' => 'Select Material', 'class' => 'form-control'], // attributes for <select>
    ['onClick' => 'showSelectedValue()'] // attributes for <option>
)}}
```